# How to transpose a column into a row in ms excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to transpose a column into row in ms excel sheet.How can I do that? Do we have any command for doing this?Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: Menu (or ribbon) Copy > Paste special and check `Transpose`

Comment: @JMax you probably should have added this as an answer - although I understand why you didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the data you want to transpose
click on the cell you want the transposed data to start in (column A in the row?)
click on the Home menu, then on the paste arrow (for more options)
Then choose Transpose

Is this what you want or is there a VBA solution you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transpose with VBA macro

```
Sub Trnspose()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet

    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDst = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    wsSrc.Range("A5:A8").Copy
    wsDst.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```