# Excel - Copy columns to rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 3 columns in a sheet in excel as below

[image: RAW DATA]

I need the output in the below format on a SEPARATE SHEET

[image: OUTPUT]

I'm fine with either VB script or using just excel features. Could I please get some help?

Comment: Is it a one-off thing or do you need to do it repeatedly for several worksheets?

Comment: Hello IT - I'll need to do this several times over the new year. So a formula/VB procedure would be awesome. Having said that, if writing one up i complicated, happy to follow another approach if you can guide please.

Comment: What's your Excel version?

Comment: Office 2010 - Windows Operating System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this macro. Place the macro in a regular code module (Insert > Module). Adjust the ranges to suit your situation.

```
Sub rearrange()
Dim cel As Range, tgt As Range

Set cel = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set tgt = ActiveSheet.Range("D1")
Do While Len(cel) > 0
    tgt = cel
    tgt.Offset(1, 0) = cel.Offset(0, 1) & cel.Offset(0, 2)
    Set cel = cel.Offset(1, 0)
    Set tgt = tgt.Offset(2, 0)
Loop
ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to do this on a regular basis, here's a simple solution.

I don't have access to MS-Excel so I cannot give you the exact answer. But I hope this helps.

Steps:

1. Add a new column with the concatenate function to the right of the table for example, to merge cells b1 and c1, use `=Concatenate(b1,c1)` and keep this result in cell D1. Do a copy-paste of the function for the other rows as well.
2. Copy your selection to a new worksheet where you want the result.
3. Use *paste special* to only paste the values of copied cells without forumulas. This ensures that it won't reference the original cells or change relatively.
4. Use the transpose function to change the resulting contents like your final output while pasting the data. Similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982131/560161).

If you need to do this regularly, this method is not suitable. You'll be better off with a VBA script. But it's been a very long time since I worked on Excel so I cannot help you there.

Comment: Transpose will not achieve what the OP is after. Also, Concatenate() is not required to combine text. The & sign is much shorter.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your time, effort & willingness to help.